# NetLogo - find minimum angle between two patches in patchset

Tags: netlogo

I'd like to find the set of patches that constitute the convex hull around a set of patches belonging to the turtle's `territory`. I was planning to use a "gift wrap" procedure to calculate the convex hull (related to below picture). [image]

I'm first finding the territory patch with the lowest `pxcor` to start at. Then, I'd like to find the territory patch that has the smallest `heading` (i.e., angle closest to zero) from the starting patch, and so on, until I arrive back at the starting patch. But I can't seem to figure out how to calculate headings between two patches. Any suggestions would be really helpful. Here is what I have so far. Eventually I will have to make this loop through each point along the outer hull.

```
patches-own [ owner-animal ]
turtles-own [ territory ]

to setup
  ca
    create-turtles 1
     [
      move-to patch-at (max-pxcor / 2) (max-pycor / 2) 
      set territory patches in-radius (2 + random 8)
      ask territory [
        set owner-animal myself
        set pcolor [ color ] of myself - 2
      ]
    ]
end

to find-convex-hull
  ask turtles
  [
    let start-patch min-one-of territory [pxcor]
    ask start-patch
    [
      let next-patch min-one-of [territory] of myself [towards self]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to find (1) the slope between two patches, or (2) the angle of the line between them relative to another line.  Is that correct?  For the first item, couldn't you just calculate the slope by subtracting `pxcor`s and `pycor`s?  For the second, you could use NetLogo's trigonometric functions.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: It is more like (2). It would be the slope between a point and all other points, but the slope needs to be relative to 0 degrees (north). This is because it is possible for the slope between a point and two other points to be equal, but the two other points are on opposite sides of 0 degree line. I was hoping the `heading` or `towards` command would work, because they give degrees relative to north.

Comment: I also notice that calculating slope by subtracting `pxcor`s from `pycor`s results in errors (cannot divide by zero) when points have the same `pxcor`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you're looking for. The only odd thing about the code is the `[towards myself - heading] of myself]` in which the first myself refers to the next turtle and the second myself refers to original, because it is the myself of the myself.

Does that make sense? Let me know if you have any questions.

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 10 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
end

to start-connecting
  ask min-one-of turtles [xcor][set heading 0 connect]
end

to connect
  let the-turtle min-one-of other turtles with [[towards myself - heading] of myself > 0] [ [towards myself - heading] of myself]
  if the-turtle = nobody [stop]
  face the-turtle
  ask the-turtle [set heading [heading] of myself]
  create-link-with the-turtle
  ask the-turtle [connect]
end
```

By the way, if you only want to do this for particular agentsets, just change which turtles you connect with in the `connect` procedure.